How to increase the memory limit in Devnet using Rust?
Now I am working with a Solana program and using serialization and deserialization. But I have memory limit error, because the memory of serialized values is too large.
How to solve this problem?

This question is similar to: What is the memory usage limit on solana's programs?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
